# multiThread modify a volatile variable, but this variable almost couldn't approach 10000

Tags: java, multithreading, volatile

I've been thinking about it for almost the whole afternoon.  Why this program its volatile variable almost couldn't approach 10000.  Here is the code:

```
public class TestModifyVolatile {
    volatile int count = 0;
    void m(){
        count++;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<>();
        TestModifyVolatile t = new TestModifyVolatile();
        for (int i=0;i<10000;i++){
            threads.add(new Thread(t::m,"t_"+i));
        }
        threads.parallelStream().forEach(e->e.start());
        threads.forEach(o->{
            try {
                o.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        System.out.println(t.count);
    }
}
```

Most of the result is 9996 9998...
Assume thread 1 starts first, thread 1 made variable count turned to 1.  In the process described above.  Maybe another thread started at the same time as thread 1 that read variable count is also 0 and wrote back 1?  That's my guess but i can not prove it

Comment: This is possible if `count++` is not an atomic increment, which probably isn't. If it is implemented as `count = count+1`, the assignment to `count` by one thread may overwrite the assignment made to count by another thread. Volatile only ensures updates are visible to all threads, it doesn't ensure atomic updates involving multiple read-writes

Comment: Burak Serdar already the correct answer. You are suffering from a race condition.

Answer (score 5):

The increment operation `count++` is not an atomic operation, even though the `count` field is variable.  In fact, it performs a volatile read followed by a volatile write.  Between the read and the subsequent write, some other thread can read the (initial) value of `count`.  So you can have the following interleaving:

```
   count is 100
   thread A:  read count -> 100
   thread B:  read count -> 100
   thread A:  write 101 to count -> 101
   thread B:  write 101 to count -> 101
```

and you have lost an increment.  (

Note that there is nothing in the current JLS that states *specifically* that volatile increment is non-atomic.  However, it follows from what the JLS 17.4 specifies for the memory visibility properties of `volatile` fields.

It is not possible to implement a reliable (thread-safe) counter using a single<sup>2</sup> `volatile` field and no additional synchronization.  Use `AtomicInteger` instead.

---

<sup>1 - It might be possible with two.  I'm not sure.</sup>

Comment: It would be good to mention race conditions @Stephen.

Comment: Well ... obviously ... the interleaving shown above is an example of a race condition.

Comment: I'm not sure it's obvious to the poster.

Comment: Contract of the volatile is that Thread B again needs to fetch from main memory. in which Thread B must use 101 from main memory instead of 100 from cpu registers

Comment: The point is that at the point where B fetches from the volatile field, the field (i.e. memory!) still contains 100.  So that is what thread B sees.